# extract and return in decimal the individual components of an RGBA color

Tags: c++, string

`char* printRGBA(unsigned int color)`

Extract and return in decimal the individual
components of an RGBA color.

An RGBA color (Red, Green, Blue,
Alpha) can be stored using a 32bit
unsigned integer in the following format: RRRRRRRR
GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB AAAAAAAA, where every component is 8 bits and has the range of (0255).

The function will return the unsigned int color as a string of decimals in the following format: "(R, G, B, A)".

For example, the color bright yellow has the integer value
of 4291559679, and is represented in binary as: 11111111 11001100 00000000 11111111, `printRGBA` would return the string: “(255, 204, 0, 255)”.

My try:

```
 char* printrgba(long long int num)
  {
int arr[64];
 cin>>num;
 int i=0,r;
 while(num!=0)
{
  r = num%2;
  arr[i++] = r;
  num /= 2;
}

 for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
 cout<<arr[j];

 }
```

I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: Hint: `cout << ((n >> 8) & 0xff) << ' ' << (n & 0xff) << endl;`

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more :/

Comment: Read up on operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you stated that you know in the original post is the key:

Your number is stored as a `32bit unsigned integer`.

The individual values are `RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB AAAAAAAA`

What you can see there, is that there are 32 individual bits, 8 each of R, G, B, and A.

One common approach to something like this then, would be to go through the 32 bit number 8 bits at a time.

To get the `AAAAAAAA` values for example:
`int a_values = num & 0x000000FF;`

The `&` operator is the `bitwise and`. That operator will extract certain parts of your number.

The bit mask denoted by the Hex string above is the `00000000000000000000000011111111`, which will allow you to get the rightmost 8 bits;

You can in this manner get each of the sets of 8 bits that you need.

Once you get your values, to get it out to your caller, you have two options:

1. Use `malloc` to reserve enough space, and `sprintf` into it.  Remember if you do this, your Caller will have to free the memory.
2. Have the caller pass a `char *` and the size of the data, and then `sprintf` into that, after making sure that there is enough room. This way, it is more obvious to your calling function that they are responsible for freeing the memory.

For option 2, there are a variety of `sprintf` related function like `snprint` that will help check the size.

If you are actually working in `c++`, but you still need to print into a `char *` anyway, the above advice holds true, but you can use a `ostringstream` to create you string in the manner

```
ostringstream stream;

stream << val1 << val2 << val3 << etc;
```

Then you can copy the data from the stringstream into the `char *` as needed.

Comment: We can't use sprintf :/