# Storing value of unsigned int variable in char array in C

Tags: c

I have 4 variables

```
unsigned r1 = 255, r2 = 204, r3 = 0, r4 = 255;
```

i need to return them as a string "(255, 204, 0, 255)"

I don't know how to add the integer values to a char *

Comment: use `malloc` and `snprintf`.

Comment: It looks like you are working on the same problem as this guy, some of my comments may be useful to you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591486/extract-and-return-in-decimal-the-individual-components-of-an-rgba-color/35591743

In C, you really aren't going to be able to get the values into a char* without using some string function like sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` for this:

```
char str[50];
sprintf(str, "(%d, %d, %d, %d)", r1, r2, r3, r4);
```

Now the string `str` contains the string `(255, 204, 0, 255)`.

Comment: The question specifically asks us not to use sprintf in the function, but to return the string as a char * and I have no idea how to do that

Comment: @Vritant Bhardwaj The [posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35591689/2410359)  says nothing about using `sprintf()` or not

Comment: Yes it slipped my mind when I was writing the question

Comment: @MLuffy Then I suggest you to update your question

Answer (score -1):

You should mention in your question that you can not use `sprintf`. If you forget while creating the question, you should mention it later. I suggest you to update your question. However here is an alternative solution without `sprintf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int  convert(unsigned char number, char* str){
    static int k = 1;  // static int is important
    int i = k, j;
    char temp;
    if (number == 0){   // handling of 0
        str[k++] = '0';
        str[k++] = ',';
        return k - 1;
    }
    while(number){
        str[k++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[number % 10];  // get reversed output 
        number = number / 10;
    }
    for (j = k - 1; i < j; i++, j--){  // reversing back the string
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
    }
    str[k++] = ',';
    return k - 1;
}

int main(){

    unsigned char r = 255;
    unsigned char g = 221;
    unsigned char b = 0;
    unsigned char a = 245;


    char color[20] = {0};  // always initialize all with 0

    int last;

    color[0] = '(';

    convert(r, color);
    convert(g, color);
    convert(b, color);
    last = convert(a, color);

    color[last] = ')';

    printf("%s\n", color);
    return 0;
}
```

The above answer can be improved a lot if you do it in `C++`